# tinyMCE setContent not working with syntax highlighted code

Tags: javascript, tinymce, syntax-highlighting

I've been stuck on this for hours and would love some help. I'm using [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) with the [syntaxhl](https://github.com/RichGuk/syntaxhl) plugin using [syntaxhighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) 2.1.382.

Everything works great with non-highlighted code. However, when using `setContent` with highlighted code, I get no joy. I'm hoping there is something obvious here I'm not seeing.

```
$(window).load(function() {
     tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('<p>here is some code:</p>
    <pre class="brush: jscript;fontsize: 100; first-line: 1; ">var fs = require("fs");

    module.exports = function(app, service){
        fs.readdir(__dirname + "/controllers", function(err, files){
            if (err) throw err;
            files.forEach(function(file){
                var name = file.replace(".js", "");
                require("./controllers/" + name)(app, service);
            });
        });
    };</pre>');
});
```

However, this doesn't work.  I've tried to debug the javascript, but I'm having trouble there to (at least with the chrome dev tools).

There is no error message, just no populated content. I've tried using {format: 'raw'} as suggested in the tinyMCE docs, but no luck there.

I'm hoping somebody else has tried to do this and succeeded.

Comment: A simple question - are you trying to use the example from your question or it is just an abstract example? JS does not support multiline strings the way you wrote them.

Comment: just an example.  However, it should be able to be any code inside the pre tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I never got the above code to work.  I think that the `<pre>` tag must take over in the browser and mess things up.  Also, I'm a bit dubious still of the line breaks causing harm.  @Thariama was some help which was great, however, after reading all the documentation on extended_valid_elements, valid_elements, and valid_children, and configuring the tinyMCE init many ways, I couldn't get this to work.

However, I did find a solution for me.  It turns out if I set the `<textarea>` directly with **encoded** html (so `<pre>` tag becomes `&lt;pre class=&quot;brush: bash;fontsize: 100; first-line: 1; &quot;&gt;`) then it works properly.  Since this is working and it cuts out having to do a `setContent` after tinyMCE is initialized, this will work for me.

The syntax highlighting is working nicely.  I came across [this link](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=tinymce%20syntax%20highlighter&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://blog.spencerkellis.net/2009/09/merging-google-syntax-highlighter-with-tinymce/&ei=cEJVT-itCufW0QWykvHdCw&usg=AFQjCNGAlgDG_C6qVu_aSwnvMGt1F07zvg&sig2=dj9YwWpUV2i6K0Ix3iR0JQ) while searching around if anyone else wants to do the same.

Comment: yepp, this will work because the'<' you enter as text are treated as entities +1

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the highlight plugin, but i guess it inserts a special stylesheet into the editor iframes head. This leads to the styling (highlighting) of special html tags a.s.o..
In this case the content is not affected/changed.

You won't be able to get your highlighted content as it looks with this plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry, I don't really understand.  I thought I'd be able to do a `setContent` on any valid html?  I'm not trying to get styling to work inside the editor.  I'm trying to `setContent` some html that the editor previously produced.  Do you see a problem with the code above?

Comment: there might be a probl3em with the default settings valid_elements and valid_children. Check the tinymce docs for further information onhowto adjust this setting.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check them out.  I do have all the defaults set at the moment.

Comment: if the settings are not set for your use case all as non valid declared html elements do get stripped out

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but no luck yet.  Everything is preserved at the time I save.  I think that extended_valid_elements would strip out the tags at save time if they weren't included.  Is that right?

Comment: yes and no, the cleanup works onSave and on some other editor events (like pasting for example)